Can one Define a Manifold with Boundary in the Context of Locally Convex Topological Vector Spaces?
I've been skipping through The Convenient Settings of Global Analysis, and came up with the following doubt: can we define manifolds with boundary in the context of locally convex topological vector spaces (lctvs)?

Naively, for real vector spaces, I could extend the definition by allowing the charts to be diffeomorphic to a $c^\infty$-open subset of
$$V' := V\cap \{v \geq 0\}$$
for some arbitrary nonzero $v$ in the lctvs $V$, where, fixing a some basis containing $v$, $\{v\geq 0\}$ is the collection of vectors which coefficient corresponding to $v$ is $\geq 0$. However, searching for "boundary" in the book does not give any similar definition, and though notations such as $\partial M$ do appear in the book, I couldn't find a definition of amanifold with boundary.

Edit: I had previously written $\{v = 0\}$, as opposed to $\{v \geq 0\}$, which was silly.

What you wrote for $V'$ does not really make sense. Instead you should pick a nonzero linear functional $f$ on $V$ and consider the inequality $f(x)\ge 0$.

@MoisheKohan could you perhaps explain why? Is that definition common?

Yes, it is standard. In the infinite-dimensional case you can find it in Lang's book. But it seems that you are not familiar even with the definition of a smooth manifold with boundary in the finite-dimensional case, which you can find pretty much in any textbook (because it is not even close to what you wrote). Can you define a half-space in $\mathbb R^n$ without using coordinates?

@MoisheKohan Also, what is the title of Lang's book?

What you wrote in the finite-dimensional case is again wrong. It seems that you have to reread some standard differential topology textbooks before trying to learn the infinite dimensional theory. Lang, "Differential manifolds."

The key sentence in your question

Naively, for real vector spaces, I could extend the definition by allowing the charts to be diffeomorphic to a $c^\infty$-open subset of

$$V' := V\cap \{v \geq 0\}$$
for some arbitrary nonzero $v$ in the lctvs $V$, where, fixing a some basis containing $v$, $\{v\geq 0\}$ is the collection of vectors which coefficient corresponding to $v$ is $\geq 0$.
makes no sense even after comments and the edit. It does not even parse on the basic syntax level. (There are also too many mathematical mistakes in one sentence, including the non-existing notion of a "$C^\infty$-open subset".)
In order to study infinite-dimensional manifolds you have to have solid background in functional analysis and you are not there yet.
What you should realize is the following in the case of $\mathbb R^n$: Each coordinate function is a (automatically continuous) nonzero linear functional on $\mathbb R^n$. For instance, $\pi_n$ is the linear functional which sends each vector $x\in \mathbb R^n$ to its $n$-th component $x_n$. Thus, when one writes "$x_n\ge 0$" it can be rewritten as "$\pi_n(x)\ge 0$."
Attempting to work with coordinates  in infinite-dimensional vector spaces is an absolutely wrong idea. Instead, you should replace the word "coordinate" with the words "nonzero (continuous) linear functional." Now, the definition of a half-space in your real TVS $V$ reads:
A subset of the form  $\{x\in V: \alpha(x)\ge 0\}$, where $\alpha\in V^*$ is nonzero.
A good exercise (in linear algebra) is to show that in the case of $V=\mathbb R^n$, every half-space (as I defined above) is obtained from the standard half-space $\mathbb H^n=\{x: x_n\ge 0\}$ by a linear change of coordinates.
For a detailed discussion of the notion of manifolds with boundary in the infinite-dimensional setting, see for instance Chapter II, section 4, in
Lang, Serge, Differential and Riemannian manifolds., Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 160. Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag. xiii, 364 p. (1995). ZBL0824.58003.
